# Make .htaccess rule work for whole website, including all subfolders?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to force redirects on my website to use a newly implemented HTTPS protocol. This is the code I've got, and I put this in the `.htaccess` file, in the root of my website:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.parkroo.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It's working fine, except I also have other `.htaccess` files in the various folders of my website, and I would like to be able to duplicate its effects across all directories on my website, rather than just working for the root of the website.

Is there a way to force this rule universally across the whole website, including all subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

It does. A .htaccess is per default working for the directory *and* its subdirectories.

Especially with RewriteRules it works that way. Otherwise it would be virtually impossible to rewrite all url's to a front controller, because per default apache maps url's to directories and files.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work in any subfolders. I have `.htaccess` files in my other folders as well, maybe that's why?

Comment: Depends, what's in it?

Comment: I mean what's in the .htaccess?

Comment: Ah or do you perhaps have a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` somewhere in your .htaccess? Could you post the full .htaccess file? I guess it's in the http root, right?